# How are aufio files smaller than 4KB proccessed during npm run build?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2

I am working on VUE.js project, which uses a tons of audio files from extra small 3-4Kb to 1MB.
Almost all my audio files are puted to folder "media" when I build my project. But audio files (MP3 format) smaller than 4KB are not moved to this "media" file. I can find them in "dist" folder at all. But they are working. Larger files can be found in dist/media folder.

Can you please give help me here, bcs I am really confused? Where are they? How there are proccessed during build?

My vue.config.js file:

```
const zlib = require("zlib");
module.exports = {
    productionSourceMap: false,
    filenameHashing: false,
  pluginOptions: {
    compression:{
      brotli: {
        filename: '[file].br[query]',
        algorithm: 'brotliCompress',
        include: /\.(js|css|html|svg|json)(\?.*)?$/i,
        compressionOptions: {
          params: {
            [zlib.constants.BROTLI_PARAM_QUALITY]: 11,
          },
        },
        minRatio: 0.8,
      },
      gzip: {
        filename: '[file].gz[query]',
        algorithm: 'gzip',
        include: /\.(js|css|html|svg|json)(\?.*)?$/i,
        minRatio: 0.8,
      }
    }
  }
}
```

thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, there is something in your build setup like Webpack's [url-loader](https://v4.webpack.js.org/loaders/url-loader/), which can convert files below a certain size threshold to Base64, and add them inline to your app source code.